# (Xcode/iOS) Provisioning profile contained invalid application identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I've never had this issue before. All of my experiences for just deploying app from Xcode to my iPhone is so flawlessly. I have 2 iPhones, with the same Apple ID. I used to deploy app from Xcode to those iPhones with no issue.

Today I had been experiencing this issue, error "Provisioning profile contained invalid application identifier" and "No profiles for 'com.****.****' were found" when I was trying to deploy an app to iPhone. But deploying to iOS Simulator is not a problem.

2 or 3 days ago, I had done deploying an app (from old project) to my first iPhone, and no problem. Today (this morning) I want to test the app to my second iPhone, but got those issue. Oddly, I still can deploy to my first iPhone since I have deployed it a few days ago and it still works.

Confused, maybe there is a problem with my second iPhone. I just create a new and fresh simple project to test deploying to my second iPhone. The result is failed and I got the same issues. When I test to my first iPhone, BOOM I got THE SAME ISSUE!

Now, I cannot deploy any app from new project to all of my iPhones. Some old apps that still work still can be deployed. But when I create a new project and try to deploy to all of my iPhone, always error. When I deployed it to Simulator, there is no such error.

Anyone knows the problem? Please help me. Thanks.

ssimage1

[image: ssimage1]

ssimage2

[image: ssimage2]

Comment: have you tried manually signing rather than automatic?

Comment: Also when suing profiles make sure your profiles are not expired too.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I haven't, do you have any tutorial to show how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: let me send you for creating profiles  and then manually signing application

Comment: Create Development profiles 
https://docs.nativescript.org/sidekick/user-guide/code-signing/code-signing-for-ios/create-development-provisioning

Comment: check your Project bundle identifier is exist on your Apple developer Account?

Comment: @SukhwinderSingh how to check that?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been a problem on Apple's side as the issue "magically" fixed itself for me after writing to the developer.apple.com support yesterday. Please try again now (and let us know whether it works).

To debug the issue in case it happens again, I would suggest:

1. looking at https://developer.apple.com/system-status/ to see whether "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" is working (in my case, no problem was reported there, despite the error...)
2. logging into a newly created local user account and creating a new iOS app project (e.g. from the Single-View template). Then try running the application on an iPhone with "Automatically manage signing" checked.

If there is no reported error and the installation fails, you can contact the developer support knowing you have done (almost) as much as possible to rule out potential already-reported or local issues.

Comment: I agree with you. My problem fixed itself. There's a bug in Apple side

Answer (score 0):

// check your Project bundle identifier is exist on your Apple developer Account?

// for check bundle id

if you have developer Account,  login with credentials, -> when you are login, so you can see there options, choose create certificate -> click on identifier and see is there any your project bundle exist or not , if not create certificate , add identifier , device Udid , provisioning profile and download it ,double tap to add in your project,
if you do not have developer you cannot add bundle id

i have some ref link to create certificates :- https://appaloosa-store.readme.io/docs/getting-started-with-apple-certificates

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that my problem is solved on its own. As I expected, there was indeed a bug. BTW thank you